# Multiple returns from jQuery AJAX post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Let me quickly explain what I do, I have multiple jQuery AJAX post which are returing different results. Here is what I'm doing at the moment:

**JavaScript**

```
$("select#be_betrieb")
  .change(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php",
      data: { action: "getkst", bkuerzel: $(this).val() },
      success: function(data) {
        $("select#be_kostenstelle").attr('disabled',false);             
        $("select#be_kostenstelle").html(data);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php",
      data: { action: "getcompnames", bkuerzel: $("select#be_betrieb").val() },
      success: function(data) {             
        $("select#be_arbeitsplatzbestehend").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

As you can see, I do a post to the same PHP file twice, just with a different action defined. Since I have several other posts to do to this file (about 6) I was wondering if there is an other way to do that?

I hope you guys understand my question. I'm looking forward to your input.

Comment: Besides putting it in a function that takes `data` and `success` as parameters, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing.  If it needs 6 calls then it needs 6 calls.  If it's something you're going to do regularly then it may make sense to return all the data from one call, but without knowing more about the situation it's hard to say whether that's worth doing.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to wrap your $.ajax call in a function. Then pass the values that changes in your action as parameters.

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: What I do in the background is depending on the "action" a different PHP method is running, which is returning my results. If there is nothing wrong the way I do it, I'm fine with that.. I was just wondering, if there is a "nicer" way to do it, since it's the first time I'm working with that.

Comment: Are you doing all those post requests one by one on change event? Or you simply select one action depending on some value?

Comment: @FAngel - on the change event I'm doing all those post.. each post returns other values which have to be applied to my form.

Answer (score 1):

based on your inputs I changed my code, can you may have an other look if that is good?

**Javascript**

```
$("select#be_betrieb")
        .change(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: 
                    { 
                        actions: [
                                    {action: "getkst", bkuerzel: $(this).val()},
                                    {action: "getcompnames", bkuerzel: $(this).val()}
                                 ]
                    },
                success: function(data)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
                        {
                            switch(data[i]["action"])
                            {
                                case "getkst":
                                    alert(data[i]["queryresult"]);
                                    break;

                                case "getcompnames":
                                    alert(data[i]["queryresult"]);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });
```

**PHP**

```
if ( $_POST['actions'] != "" )
{
foreach ($_POST['actions'] as $action)
{
    switch ($action['action'])
    {
        case "getkst":

            $queryresult = "here something to return";

            $results[] = array('action' => 'getkst', 'queryresult' => $queryresult);
            break;

        case "getcompnames":

            $queryresult = "here something to return";

            $results[] = array('action' => 'getcompnames', 'queryresult' => $queryresult);
            break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: check my answer, that keeps almost the same logic you are after, but with a more concise and organized way to it http://stackoverflow.com/a/13549732/647380

Answer (score 0):

Once you are sending all of those requests one by one, to the same page, I think it would be better to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php",
      dataType:'json',
      data: {actions: [{action: "getkst", bkuerzel: $(this).val()},
                       {action: "getcompnames", bkuerzel: $("select#be_betrieb").val()},
                       ...] },
      success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
            switch(data[i]["action"]) {
                case "getkst":
                    $("select#be_kostenstelle").attr('disabled',false);             
                    $("select#be_kostenstelle").html(data[i].resultHTML);
                    break;
                case "getcompnames":
                    $("select#be_arbeitsplatzbestehend").html(data[i].resultHTML);
                    break;
            }
        }
      }
    });
```

And in your `/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php` return array of results encoded with [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

`dataType:'json'` this will let jQuery know that it should handle response like JSON, so data will contain regular JS object.

Reasons:

- one request leading to lower load on server (no need to initialize
  environment for 6 request)
- faster (each request require some time to
  connect to server, also there could be a problem with session lock:
  once you are using default session all requests will be used one by
  one, waiting for previouse request to be finished)

Basic idea is to push all actions and its values with one AJAX request. Than, on server, iterate through `$_POST['actions']` and execute what you need for each action. Collect results into PHP array like this:

```
 $results = array(array("action" => 'action1', 
                        "results" => "some action results"), 
                  array("action" => 'action2', 
                        "results" => "some action results"),
                  ...);
```

and than encode that array with json_encode, so jQuery can parse it:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, not sure if you got me right, or maybe I just don't understand it :-) on the change event I always have to do all those requests. And I don't see how to handle the PHP part since I never did something similar.. but I think I got at least a starting point with your description, thanks for that.

Comment: @Crasher PHP part could be handled similar to JS part (see switch in `success` handler). Just loop through items in $_POST['actions'] and use action name to decide what to do. Output results into some variable instead of echo to client immediately.

Answer (score 0):

you may use a library that does that automatically for you, even chaining AJAX responses when it's done, but instead of doing it client side, you call the ajax functions from the server side. using phery library ( http://phery-php-ajax.net ) you can do it all from the server:

```php
<select data-remote="getkst" name="bkuerzel" data-target="/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php">
   // fill your options here
</select>
```

in your `antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php` file

```php
function getcompnames($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;  
  // get your comp names here. If you are appending to a select, use
  $r->jquery('select#be_arbeitsplatzbestehend')->html($html_content);
  return $r;
}

function getkst($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse; 
  $html_content = set_your_html_content();

  $r
  ->jquery('select#select#be_kostenstelle')
  ->removeAttr('disabled')->html($html_content);
  // you could do
  // $r->phery_remote('getcompnames', array('bkuerzel' => $data['bkuerzel']), array('target' => '/functions/antragsformulare_benutzer.inc.php'));
  // to call a second ajax when this one is completed, but it's best to merge the response from getcompnames and keep it all in one single AJAX call
  return $r->merge(getcompnames());
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'getkst' => 'getkst',
  'getcompnames' => 'getcompnames'
))->process();
```

As you can see, you can either call a second AJAX response, or merge the both answers, which I think it's the best bet for you, and save one AJAX call ;)